# How to disbale SSL in logstash configuration?

Tags: ssl, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using logstash-forwarder with logstash but I don't want to use SSL. I tried with setting the SSL parameter to false in LogStash config file then I am getting compilation error. I removed SSL parameter as well but then I got error while compiling stated as :

Missing a required setting for the lumberjack input plugin:

```
input {
    lumberjack {
      ssl_certificate => # SETTING MISSING
      ...
    }
  } {:level=>:error}
```

Here is my logstash.conf file :

```
input {
lumberjack {
  port => 5000
  type => "logs"
  ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
      }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => "ec2-52-34-246-71.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash-forwarder requires encryption; it's just part of what it does.

The replacement for logstash-forwarder, [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat), makes it optional.